# How the Output was 1 and 4 . I cant understand the logic behind the c program?

Tags: c

**How the Output was  1 and 4 . I cant understand the logic behind the c program?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int i = 4;
    a = 24 || --i;
    printf("%d %d",a,i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 4

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit the console.
```

**Can anyone explain the logic for the program..........**

Comment: What would you expect it to output ?

Comment: ||   is logical OR, so it could be `1`or `0`

Comment: || is a logical or, so it is returning true or 1 so the output is 1 and 4

Comment: probably because it finds a= 24 true first and does not check the right side of the equation, furthermore, even if it did decrement it you are not storing the result anywhere.

Comment: @Mike There is no 3 involved. `--i` is never executed

Comment: @SeanPowell "... even if it did decrement it you are not storing the result anywhere" is wrong. `--i` is the same as `i = i - 1`

Comment: `a = expr1 || expr2;` is like `if (expr1 == TRUE) {a = 1;} else if (expr2 == TRUE) {a = 1;} else {a = 0;}`

Comment: @4386427 yea, you are right, too much of other languages

Comment: @SeanPowell May I suggest that you delete the comment as it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the language C has 0 as the value for `false` and all non-zero numbers as `true`.

So, from the viewpoint of an optimising compiler you get:

```
a = 24 || --i;
a = TRUE OR --i;

=> "TRUE OR ..." is always TRUE, so just skip it!
Hence: 
a == 1 (which means "TRUE")
```

And what about `i`? Well, nothing happened, so it just keeps having its original value.

Comment: I understand your explanation thanks for your answer

Comment: Optimization is irrelevant; by the rules of the C standard, `24 || --i` must not evaluate `--i` regardless of whether optimization is used.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy evaluation. Take a look at this line:

```
a = 24 || --i;
```

the `||` operator first evaluates the left hand side operand. If it evaluates to `true` then the right hand side of it won't get evaluated, as it doesn't matter.

Now, why is `a` actually `1`? As a matter of fact, it's a version of `true` since it's the result of a boolean expression and it is cast from `bool` to `int` upon assignment, resulting in a value of `1`. The `i` prints `4` because the `--i` isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 24 || --i;
```

|| is the logical or.

A 24 is true (not 0). Therefore the second Part of the Or (--i) will be skipped.

There is no need to evaluate it, as the first part is already found to be true. So i will NOT be decremented and stay at 4

Comment: "There is no need to evaluate it ..." Well, it's not just "no need" ! The C standard forbids that it is evaluated.